# Cannot read enum property, ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

For my model I have problem with reading enum property. After reading from mongoDB, the property 'value' has type String instead of MyEnum.

My model:

```
public class Record {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public Wrapper<MyEnum> wrappedEnum;
   ...
}

public class Wrapper<T extends Enum<?>> extends BaseWrapper<T>{
    ...
}

public class BaseWrapper<T> {
    public T value;
    ...
}
```

Code:

```
 Record record = new Record();
        Wrapper<MyEnum> wrapper = new Wrapper<>();
        wrapper.setValue(MyEnum.A);
        record.setWrappedEnum(wrapper);
        repository.save(record);


        repository.findAll().forEach(rec -> {
            Object value = rec.getWrappedEnum().value;
            System.out.println("rec.getWrappedEnum().value: " + value); // rec.getWrappedEnum().value: A
            System.out.println("rec.getWrappedEnum().getValue(): " + value.getClass()); // rec.getWrappedEnum().getValue(): class java.lang.String
            MyEnum valEnum = rec.getWrappedEnum().getValue(); // throws Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.example.MyEnum (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.MyEnum is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        });
```

Is any option to configure mongodb to read this model correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a ClassCastException is because you didn't specify how the persistence layer should actually persist your wrapped enum.

I suppose you are using JPA as the persistence API. There are actually multiple ways to achieve what you want. The more convenient way for your case would be to register a converter, so that JPA knows how to persist your Enum and map it back. A basic example could look like this (Note that there are setter for the value field in BaseWrapper):

```
@Converter
public class WrapperConverter implements AttributeConverter<Wrapper, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Wrapper attribute) {
    return attribute.getValue().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public Wrapper convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.valueOf(dbData);
    Wrapper<MyEnum> wrappedEnum = new Wrapper<>();
    wrappedEnum.setValue(myEnum);
    return wrappedEnum;
  }
}
```

Register the converter:

```
@Entity
public class Record {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Convert(converter = WrapperConverter.class)
  private Wrapper<MyEnum> wrappedEnum;
```

Comment: It isn't the sollution. Please note that if I change the model to:
```
public class Record {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public MyEnum myEnum;
   ...
}``` the issue will not occur. 
I think that problem can be related to inheritance and generic types in the model.

Comment: Okay got you. The converter can also be set on the field directly. Look at the edit i made on the previous answer